# MVC-Based JSP-Servlet-JDBC Login

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jdbc

I've set up a login form using both jsp and servlet. I used the servlet as the controller and the jsp as the model. Here are the codes:

JSP:

```
<%@page import="com.horizon.entity.Users"%>
<%@page import="com.horizon.da.UserDA"%>
<%@page import="com.horizon.service.UserService"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome to Horizon Airways</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Welcome to</h2><br>
<h1 align="center">Horizon Airways</h1><br><hr>
<form action="./login.do" method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<th>User name: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Pass word: </th>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Login">

</td>
<td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
package com.horizon.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.horizon.da.UserDA;
import com.horizon.entity.Users;
import com.horizon.service.UserService;



public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ControllerServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            if(path.equals("/login.do")) {
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                UserService service = new UserService();
                UserDA da = new UserDA();
                service.setDA(da);
                Users user = da.verifyUser(username, password);
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
                String address = null;
                if(user.getRole() == "Business Manager")
                    address = "./view.jsp";
                else if(user.getRole() == "Counter Assistant")
                    address = "./manage.jsp";
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And here's the error:

> Nov 28, 2014 12:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke
>       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ControllerServlet] in context with path [/HorizonAirways] threw exception
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.horizon.servlet.ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:43)
>         at com.horizon.servlet.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:49)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I appreciate anyone who helps me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
String address = null;//<-- is null, if below conditions didn't match
if(user.getRole() == "Business Manager")
    address = "./view.jsp";
else if(user.getRole() == "Counter Assistant")
    address = "./manage.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);//<-- might be null
dispatcher.forward(request, response);//<-- raises NPE, if null
```

P.S. avoid using `==` use `.equals()` instead. Kindly verify the `user role` here.

You can try this:

```
String address = "./invalid.jsp";//<-- default page, if role not match
if(user.getRole().equals("Business Manager"))
    address = "./view.jsp";
else if(user.getRole().equals("Counter Assistant"))
    address = "./manage.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I tested your suggestion, Arvind, and it worked. Thank you very much. I've been stressing this code for hours

Comment: @randomprogrammer you can check my answer too and give your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your address is empty.

```
if(user.getRole() == "Business Manager")
    address = "./view.jsp";
else if(user.getRole() == "Counter Assistant")
  address = "./manage.jsp";
else
  System.println.out(address);   //Try to print the address here and see what's going
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NPE at line 43 in `doGet()` as said in stacktrace.
As others said use `equals()` rather than `==` , I recommend use `equalsIgnoreCase()` , it is more reliable when it comes to `case Of String`returned by `user.getRole()`.

It won't really matter if your `user.getRole()` returns *Business Manager* OR *business manager* OR *BUSINESS MANAGER* .

Real reason you should not return `==` is :- It is used to check if two object reference variables [NOT two Objects] refers to the same object or not.

An object reference variable contains the address of the Object it refers to.
Object reference variable is not an Object. It is just a mapping to access the real Object.

So, In you case here `user.getRole() == "Business Manager"`  , the `"Business Manager"` is a String literal and `intern()` is called on it `implicitly` which returns reference location of String literal in String Pool/intern Pool & `user.getRole()` returns a String Object reference variable which points to a String Object in Heap. So, according to `==` they do not have same Address.

So your check `user.getRole() == "Business Manager"` fails.

You should use `equalsIgnoreCase()` or you can call `intern()` on `user.getRole()` Like this `if(user.getRole().intern() == "Business Manager")` OR `if("Business Manager" == user.getRole().intern())` .